# Linux: tee usage misunderstanding

Tags: linux, tee

1. When I use

```
$ ls | tee log.txt
```

I get correct, expected result: log.txt keeps 'ls' output.

2. I need to save output of the command:

```
$ svnadmin dump MyRepo -r1:r2 > dumpfile
* Dumped revision 1.
* Dumped revision 2.
```

Where "$ svnadmin .." is command and
"* Dumped .." are outputs

3. So, the question itself. When I run the command:

```
$ svnadmin dump MyRepo -r1:r2 > dumpfile | tee log.txt
* Dumped revision 1.
* Dumped revision 2.
```

log.txt has 0 size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** -- Try this one:

```
svnadmin dump MyRepo -r1:r2 2>&1 > dumpfile | tee log.txt
```

**Explanation:** Each command has three connected "standard streams": Standard Input (STDIN, filehandle 0), Standard Output (STDOUT, 1) and Standard Error (STDERR, 2). Usually commands ouput their "data" on STDOUT and errors on STDERR.

A simple command like `ls` has all three of them connected to the console. Because both STDOUT and STDERR are connected to the console the output of the command is interleaved.

A "pipe" like `ls | tee log.txt` redirects STDOUT of the first command to STDIN of the second command. No more - no less. Therefore all other streams are still connected to the console. Should the `ls` part produce error messages they will be written to the console, **not** to the file! But your `ls` example did not output any errors so you didn't notice.

After the pipe is setup the shell evaluates the other redirection operator of the first command -- from left to right.

Therefore `svnadmin dump > dumpfile | tee log.txt` will redirect STDOUT of `svnadmin` to `dumpfile` leaving effectively no data for the `tee` command because that's a *redirection*, not a *copy*.

`svnadmin dump MyRepo 2>&1 > dumpfile | tee log.txt` adds another redirection step. It reads "make filehandle 2 (STDERR) a copy of the filehandle 1 (STDOUT)" which is the pipe at this point. Writing to either STDOUT or STDERR will write to the pipe. But after that the `> dumpfile` redirection is applied and STDOUT is redirected to the file.

You can read all this (and much more) in the shell's manual. For `bash` it is in the section `REDIRECTION`.

Comment: Thank you, may be add some explanation: why original version does not work